# Checking info infinite loop + Play store blank screen

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, application-error

whenever I try to login using a google account, no matter the application, I get stuck in a page with "Checking info..." and an activity indicator, just nothing happens. Also, when I try to open the Play Store I get a never ending blank screen so I can't download any app nor update the ones I already have on my mobile.

What I already tried:

1. Suspending account synch.
2. Clearing cache and data for Google Play, Google Play Services, Google Frameworks.
3. Uninstalling updates for Play Store, which anyway failed with unknown error.

I'm running Android 8.0 on an European (Spanish) Galaxy S7 Edge.

Comment: Installing updates should be the right approach, you just tried to update the wrong app. The relevant app is the PlayServices app which implements login and large parts of the communication with Google servers. Also clear data of Playstore and PlayServices app.

Comment: @Robert: how do I update Play Services if I don't have access to PlayStore?

Comment: There are a lot of web sites providing APKs for download.

Comment: @Robert: I downloaded and installed updates for Play Store and Play Services, now the store doesn't show an everlasting white screen anymore, but the checking info loop is still there, so basically I'm virtually locked out from the store.

Comment: What phone do you use and what Android version is installed?